# Interfaces and overload directive

Tags: delphi

The following code throws me the compiler error

> E2252 Method 'MyFunction' with identical parameters already exists

```
program Project3;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  aMyInterface = interface
    function MyFunction(const aSort: Integer; var aEndPoint: Integer): Integer; overload;
    function MyFunction(const aSort, aStartingPoint: Integer): Integer; overload;
  end;

  aMyClass = class(TInterfacedObject, aMyInterface)
    function MyFunction(const aSort: Integer; var aEndPoint: Integer): Integer; overload;
    function MyFunction(const aSort, aStartingPoint: Integer): Integer; overload;
  end;

{ aMyClass }

function aMyClass.MyFunction(const aSort: Integer; var aEndPoint: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

function aMyClass.MyFunction(const aSort, aStartingPoint: Integer): Integer;
begin
  Result := 1;
end;

begin
end.
```

I understand there are two variables Integer type for each instance of the function but in one function both variables are both **const** and in the other function one variable one is **const** and the other one is **var**.

Why isn't that sufficient not to be considered identical parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the overload resolution decision is taken by considering the calling code and not the declaration.

Suppose you call the function like this:

```
MyFunction(int1, int2);
```

Which one do you expect to be called? The const overload or the var overload? The compiler has no means to take that decision. Hence this is deemed ambiguous.

Comment: I have never considered looking at the calling code compiler point of view. I have learned something very new today.